# How to upload the public url for an image uploaded to the Firebase Cloud Storage to the Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

After uploading an image to the Firebase Cloud Storage, I want to add its public download URL to a child node in my realtime database.

My File Upload Code

```
    private void uploadFile() {

        if (imageUri != null) {

            StorageReference fileRef = storageReference.child(UID + "/pic" + ".png");

            UploadTask uploadTask =  fileRef.putFile(imageUri);
            uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(OrderPickupActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    fileRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            imageURL = uri.toString();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(OrderPickupActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Choose an image!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

Uploading to the realtime database

```
uploadFile();

                    PickupDetails newPickup = new PickupDetails(
                            date,
                            time,
                            name,
                            email,
                            address,
                            pinCode,
                            UID,
                            phoneNumber,
                            imageURL
                    );

                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Pending-Requests")
                            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                            .setValue(newPickup)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    //Toast.makeText(OrderPickupActivity.this, "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    startActivity(new Intent(OrderPickupActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                                }
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(OrderPickupActivity.this, "Error, " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                            });
```

Pickup Details class

```
public class PickupDetails {

    public String date, time, userName, userEmail, userAddress, pinCode, userUID, phoneNumber, image;

    public PickupDetails(String date, String time, String userName, String userEmail, String userAddress, String pinCode, String userUID, String phoneNumber, String image) {
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
        this.userAddress = userAddress;
        this.pinCode = pinCode;
        this.userUID = userUID;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

I have used the answers from similar questions on StackOverflow, but none of them seems to help me. When I log the result, I am able to get the value, but it does not reach the database.

Comment: It looks like you haven't actually made an attempt to write anything to Realtime Database.

Comment: I did...I'm sorry I did not add it in the question

Comment: Without seeing the code that doesn't work the way you expect, along with a more complete description of what you're trying to accomplish, there's little we can do to help.

Comment: I added the code where I add it to the database, the main issue is, all the other values are visible in the database other than the imageURL

Comment: Probably because the database is being updated before the upload completes.   Put some logging statements in your code to debug it and see how it's actually working.  Firebase APIs are all asynchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [Doug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807126/doug-stevenson), firebase APIs are asynchronous, which means, they will work in the background while letting the rest of your logic work. The trick was to submit to the database **after** the task was done. All I had to do was to move my adding to database logic in the onSuccessListener.

Answer (score 0):

In onSuccess method of your getDownloadUrl listener:

```
databaseRef.child("images").push().setValue(uri.toString())
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image uri saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error occured.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```